# Can the French "moralistes" be considered as (Renaissance) humanists?

Tags: humanism

Can the French "moralistes" of the XVIIth century be considered as (Renaissance) humanists, and if not why?

Thinking here about the moralistic figures of the French classicism: Jean de La Fontaine (1621-1695), La Rochefoucauld (1613-1680), La Bruyère (1645-1696), Bossuet (1627-1704).

I stambled upon this [sentence](https://lettres.ac-versailles.fr/spip.php?article635) (DeepL Translation): "Montaigne, La Rochefoucauld and La Bruyère are the first of our moralistic writers and perhaps also those who best understood the human heart."

Although I never heard that La Rochefoucault and La Bruyère were Renaissance Humanists, I think Montaigne is without controversy considered as one.
Also saw that Blaise Pascal was considered as a moralist, although similarly, I know he is mainly seen as a Renaissance humanist.

I know that Renaissance is supposed to end at the beginning of the XVIth century.